# Rewrite rule 301 with different formatting

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Okay, so I need to find the correct syntax for what I want to do.

These links:

```
http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/product1/
(...)
http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/product700/
```

need to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/sub3/product1-newsite/
(...)
http://www.example.com/sub3/product700-newsite/
```

What I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sub1/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdir/$1-newsite/ [R=301,L]
```

For all the 700 products. 
Also I need to make exeptions for certain products.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What location are you redirected to for (say) http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/product1/ ?

Comment: I now have 700 rules:
Redirect 301 /sub1/sub2/product1 http://www.example.com/sub3/product1-newsite
My .htaccess is now almost 80 kbytes and looking for a way to slim down the filesize.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the numbering on the regular expression that is an issue.

$1 is the first matched group, $2 is the second, etc. $0 is for the entire string that matched (ie. the whole path).

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sub1/sub2/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdir/$1-newsite/ [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sub1/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdir/$2-newsite/ [R=301,L]
```

**Edit**

Ah... had a thought... the first regex in the capture may be being a bit too greedy... since it can match:

`^/sub1/[sub2/product1-newsite]/[]` so $1 will be `sub2/product1-newsite` and $2 will be empty (.* can happily match nothing).

So we need to make sure it doesn't grab too much.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sub1/([^/]+)/(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/subdir/$2-newsite/ [R=301,L]
```

Changing the `*` to `+` makes sure we match at least one character.

Changing the `.` to `[^/]` makes sure we match "anything except a /".

Added a `/` on the end to make sure the $2 doesn't capture the trailing slash.

That should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.
The first suggestion is no option, because the second subdir changes per product.
The second suggestion is not redirecting anything. Got another idea?

Comment: Updated the answer